# How to use if, else with SED or AWK?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, centos

I have to insert few lines under a particular section in a file. For this I need to write a shell script. The problem is that particular section may or may not be present in the file.
If the section [oslo_concurrency] is not present in the file, It should first insert [oslo_concurrency] at the end of the file and the line 'lock_path = /var/lock/cinder' should be added below the [oslo_concurrency] section. If the section [oslo_concurrency] is present it should just the line 'lock_path = /var/lock/cinder' below [oslo_concurrency] section.

Can I accomplish this task using SED or AWK, if no whats the simplest way. Kindly guide me through this scenario.

Output file looks like.

```
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lock/cinder
```

Comment: I believe that i saw something for this on youtube but i cant remember :/

Comment: What do you want to do if the section is not present in the file?

Comment: https://github.com/albfan/bash-ini-parser

Comment: You can do what you want with Awk.  The problem we face is that we don't have a complete specification of what you want to do.  You've not shown us what needs to be added; you've not described what should happen if the data to be added was added once before; you've not described what should happen if the marker (section heading) is not present; you've not said whether the new material should go immediately after the marker or at the end of the section; you've not said whether the section is terminated by a blank line or a new marker, etc.

Comment: `if/then/else` available in `awk`. Please spend an hour or two working thru some `awk` tutorials. You may find http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html to be of help. Good luck.

Comment: @miken32 I wrote a SED command to insert the line under the [oslo_concurrency]         sed -i '/[oslo_concurrency]/s/$/\nlock_path = \/va\/lock\/cinder/' /etc/cinder/cinder.conf

Answer (score 1):

If its a single line section header after the first line you can use `sed` replace:

```
file: test.txt

test data 1
test data 2
[oslo_concurrency]
test data 3
test data 4
test data 5
test data 6
test data 7
test data 8
test data 9
test data 10


function print_header() { 
cat << EOF
lock_path = /var/lock/cinder 
$(date '+%B %d, %Y @ ~ %r')  ID:$RANDOM
EOF
}
```

`echo "$(print_header)" | sed '/\[oslo_concurrency\]/r/dev/stdin' test.txt`

Result:

```
    test data 1
    test data 2
    [oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lock/cinder 
December 05, 2015 @ ~ 01:31:57 AM  ID:3115
    test data 3
    test data 4
    test data 5
    test data 6
    test data 7
    test data 8
    test data 9
    test data 10
```